# CakePHP Bakery Error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to bake my controllers but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

It's making me frightfully sad, has anyone ever come across this?

Comment: We need your controller code.

Comment: there is no controller, I'm trying to generate one with the bakery.

Comment: Is there any existing code in your project? What was your last change?

Comment: Fresh project, all I did was create two database tables (Users and Folders), then I baked the Models. After the models were baked I moved on to Controllers and this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Folders is a protected name for the Folder class, or at least the cause of the issue. You may need to change the name of this to something different.

Comment: Cheers, that was the issue. I googled all of the other protected names as well so I don't do it again :)